# Align Note below table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My question concerns the "Note" below the table. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{ Descriptive statistics of total sample based on modified data set}\label{table:descrtotal}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{l|rrr}
\hline\hline
 & \% E & n UE & n E\\ \hline
No Denomination & 0.63 & 1425 & 2470\\ 
Buddhist & 0.70 & 312 & 731\\ 
Hindu & 0.24 & 482 & 149\\ 
Muslim & 0.23 & 3993 & 1185\\ 
Orthodox & 0.51 & 1574 & 1609\\ 
Other Christian groups & 0.53 & 697 & 779\\ 
Other Denominations & 0.53 & 294 & 326\\ 
Other Muslim groups & 0.14 & 1428 & 238\\ 
Protestant & 0.55 & 1214 & 1472\\ 
Roman Catholic & 0.56 & 2031 & 2550\\ 
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\\
\tiny Note: Share of aliens employed (\% E), Number of aliens unemployed (n UE) and Number of aliens employed (n E).\\
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I would like to aligne the Note such that it starts where the ligne starts and breaks where the line ends - is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Whatever answer you accept, [use `\centering` instead of `center`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your note as an additional row spanning all four columns via `\multicolumn`. Making longer texts break in tables is possible with a `minipage`. The downside is, however, that you have to guesstimate the width of your table (I put in `6.5cm`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ Descriptive statistics of total sample based on modified data set}\label{table:descrtotal}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l|rrr}
\hline\hline
 & \% E & n UE & n E\\ \hline
No Denomination & 0.63 & 1425 & 2470\\ 
Buddhist & 0.70 & 312 & 731\\ 
Hindu & 0.24 & 482 & 149\\ 
Muslim & 0.23 & 3993 & 1185\\ 
Orthodox & 0.51 & 1574 & 1609\\ 
Other Christian groups & 0.53 & 697 & 779\\ 
Other Denominations & 0.53 & 294 & 326\\ 
Other Muslim groups & 0.14 & 1428 & 238\\ 
Protestant & 0.55 & 1214 & 1472\\ 
Roman Catholic & 0.56 & 2031 & 2550\\ 
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{%
  \begin{minipage}{6.5cm}%
    \tiny Note: Share of aliens employed (\% E), Number of aliens unemployed (n UE) and Number of aliens employed (n E).%
  \end{minipage}%
}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: I doubt that it's good style, but you get nicer-looking spacing before the note if you add an empty line (`~\\`) before it:

```
  \begin{minipage}{6.5cm}~\\
    \tiny Note: ...
```

Does anybody by chance have a solution how to get the width of the table automatically for the `minipage`?

---

Edit2: Used `\centering` and `\footnotesize`, as suggested.

Comment: see my answer for the automatic width; if you need to add some vertical space it's better to say `\rule{0pt}{12pt}Note` (change 12pt to suit).

Comment: @egreg: I've read up a bit on boxing and I think I understand how your autowidth works. However, I don't know how to apply it to my solution because I need `\wd\tablebox` for `\begin{minipage}{\wd\tablebox}` within the table and thus before `\end{lrbox}`. Compiling [this](http://pastebin.com/Gav4cj1f) results in 26 overfull/underfull boxes and no output for the table.

Comment: Setting the note as a `\multicolumn` requires to typeset twice the table: at first without the note, so you can measure the width; then with the final row. It's much easier to add the minipage after the table.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, thanks. I didn't edit it in, though, because that'd basically leave my answer the same as yours just with a `minipage` instead of your `parbox`. As of now, I like your answer better, but maybe someone'll come up with a autowidth fix for mine. For now, thanks for the box business, this'll come in really useful in the future!

Answer (score 20):

Yet another option, which doesn't use explicit `\parbox`es or `minipage`s, would be to use the [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package (the `para` and `flushleft` options give the desired placement):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering\footnotesize
  \caption{Descriptive statistics of total sample based on modified data set}
  \label{table:descrtotal}\medskip
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
    \toprule
    & \% E & n UE & n E \\
    \midrule
    No Denomination & 0.63 & 1425 & 2470 \\ 
    Buddhist & 0.70 & 312 & 731 \\ 
    Hindu & 0.24 & 482 & 149 \\ 
    Muslim & 0.23 & 3993 & 1185 \\ 
    Orthodox & 0.51 & 1574 & 1609 \\ 
    Other Christian groups & 0.53 & 697 & 779 \\ 
    Other Denominations & 0.53 & 294 & 326 \\ 
    Other Muslim groups & 0.14 & 1428 & 238 \\ 
    Protestant & 0.55 & 1214 & 1472 \\ 
    Roman Catholic & 0.56 & 2031 & 2550 \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  Note: Share of aliens employed (\% E), Number of aliens unemployed (n 
UE) and Number of aliens employed (n E).
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: moving the `\caption` and `\label` commands inside the `threeparttable` environment will also adjust the width of the caption to match the one of the table.

Comment: looks great if you start your footnote text with \scriptsize

Comment: It would have been better to place the `\caption` and `\label` directives inside rather than before the `threeparttable` environment, as that way the caption's width would have been set to that of the `tabular` environment as well.

Answer (score 11):

I propose a different approach: set the table in a box, and append the note beneath it in a parbox of the same width. I've also used **booktabs** to make the table more pleasant

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Descriptive statistics of total sample based on modified data 
set}\label{table:descrtotal}
\medskip
\footnotesize
\begin{lrbox}{\tablebox}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
 & \% E & n UE & n E\\
\midrule
No Denomination & 0.63 & 1425 & 2470\\ 
Buddhist & 0.70 & 312 & 731\\ 
Hindu & 0.24 & 482 & 149\\ 
Muslim & 0.23 & 3993 & 1185\\ 
Orthodox & 0.51 & 1574 & 1609\\ 
Other Christian groups & 0.53 & 697 & 779\\ 
Other Denominations & 0.53 & 294 & 326\\ 
Other Muslim groups & 0.14 & 1428 & 238\\ 
Protestant & 0.55 & 1214 & 1472\\ 
Roman Catholic & 0.56 & 2031 & 2550\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\usebox{\tablebox}\\[1ex]
\parbox{\wd\tablebox}{Note: Share of aliens employed (\% E), Number of aliens unemployed (n 
UE) and Number of aliens employed (n E).}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `center` environment should not be used inside `table` (use `\centering`) and that the `footnotesize` environment does not exist. It's possible to use it, but in certain circumstances it might bite you. `:-)`. A `\tiny` paragraph is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that I like for these kind of auxiliary explanations is to

- Encapsulate the table in a minipage.
- Add a footnote to the first table header that expounds on the table columns.
- Use the footmisc package so you can make each column reference that same footnote.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been brought up again by [this duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58748/14697). A refinement of @GonzaloMedina's answer is the `\note` command provided by `threeparttablex` when loaded with the `referable` option*; a similar `\source` command too is available.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            a & b & c\\\toprule
            some column text & some column text & some column text\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \footnotesize
            \note \lipsum[1]
        \end{tablenotes}
        \caption{A table.}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note that the `\note` command is designed to work in `threeparttable`'s original environment; it is *not* intendend to (and will not correctly) work in `threeparttablex`'s own `ThreePartTable` environment.