# Specific layout when adding nornmal text below a tabular in a table-environment

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Align Note below table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19991/align-note-below-table)

I have a tabular inside a table-environment and wish to add some explanatory text directly below the tabular within the float. Of course I know that I should explain the contents of the table in my normal text and will do so. But in this case I need some special information given directly below the tabular. So far, I've come up with the solutuion below. But there are two problems I can't solve.

1. I'd like the text to be justified like the normal text (full-justification, in German "Blocksatz"), neither centered nor left-justified nor right-justified. I haven't found a way to manually set the text justified.
2. I'd like the text to be of the same width as the tabular above and, while justified, be placed directly below the centered tabular. The width of the tabular is not given manually (by the starred tabular-version or the like), but determined by the contents of the tabular. I thought about adding multicolums to the table, but that is only conditionally feasible as I need to set every line break manually and still have no justified text.

Is there any way to solve one or preferraby both of these issues?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
some text & some more text\\
some text & which determines the width of the tabular\\
\end{tabular}\\
\blindtext
\caption{Test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note multicolumn can take `p` columns so do allow justification and automatic breaking. However you may want to look at the `threeparttable` package.

Comment: I seem to have used the wrong keywords in my previous searches as  I missed the dublicate question. It just showed in the "related" side bar after finishing my question. The solution with `threeparttable` solves my issues.

Comment: In reference to your introductory words: Your case is covered by the Chicago Manual of Style and not uncommon. As an extension of `threeparttable`, an out-of-the-box solution is provided by `threeparttablex`, see [my answer to the duplicate question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58813/14697).