# Table with horizontal line that doesn't span all columns

Tags: tables, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/how-can-i-draw-a-horizontal-line-spanning-only-some-of-the-table-cells)

I need to recreate table 12 of [this document](http://www.ianwatson.com.au/stata/tabout_tutorial.pdf) manually (because unfortunately this automatic program doesn't seem to work properly).

[image]

I think a unique aspect is a horizontal line that doesn't span all columns.

Comment: Look in the manual of `booktabs`; the short lines are produced with `\cmidrule`.

Comment: Further, refer to `siunitx` for columns aligned at the decimal point. How to place a note below the table is [demonstrated in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58813/14697) (`threeparttablex` also offers a `\source` command). For the environment, you may start with a `tabular` to keep it simple and possibly extend e.g. to a `tabu` later on. Placement of the tabular inside a `table` is optional, but usually desirable.

Comment: I took the liberty to make your question conform with our standards here better, i.e. to have a specific title and to contain only one question. The other question about the proper environment is rather trivial, have a look at sections 2.11.6 and 2.12 of [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf). Also,the question on partial lines has been asked already, so this question will be closed as a duplicate. If you still have trouble with that table, reproduce it as far as you can and then ask a new question about one specific feature you're struggling with.

Comment: @egreg: I added a `booktabs` answers to the predecessor of this duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59035/4012