# Annotation for table following the APA style

Tags: tables, apa-style

I started to translate a table into German and building it in a LaTeX document following the APA guidelines (please ignore the missing label and caption or the missing Rho and other formatting stuff ;) ...):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Durchschnitt} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{80\% GI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% KI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
        Merkmal & k & N & r & p & SD & UG & OG & UG & OG \\
        \cmidrule{1-10}
        Neurotizismus & 48 & 8,025 & --.17 & --.24 & .18 & --.47 & --.01 & --.30 & --.18 \\
        Extraversion & 60 & 11,705 & .22 & .31 & .17 & .09 & .53 & .26 & .36 \\
        Offenheit & 37 & 7,221 & .16 & .24 & .11 & .09 & .38 & .19 & .28 \\
        Verträglichkeit & 42 & 9,801 & .06 & .08 & .17 & --.14 & .29 & .02 & .13 \\
        Gewissenhaftigkeit & 35 & 7,510 & .20 & .28 & .17 & .06 &.51 & .22 & .34 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What's missing is the annotation I'd like to add underneath the table, that shall have only the width of the table itself like in the original table ("Note"):

[image]

Does anyone have ideas how to include such an annotation?

Thanks in advance, appreciate your support!
Florian

Comment: You could use the `tabularray` package, that allows notes and remarks to be inserted.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take a look at the `tablenotes` environment provided by the `threeparttable` package. See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20007/134144

Comment: Off-topic: IMNSHO,  it's dubious practice to employ `--` (en-dash) when what is really needed is a math-mode `-` (minus) symbol. For the font that's used in your screenshot, the two symbols happen to look reasonably similar. However, that's not the case with all fonts.

Comment: Thanks Mico, you're absolutely right ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out you have all the components to achieve what you're asking already available in the `nicematrix` package. According to section 13.3 of the manual you can enter and adapt tabular notes in a `NiceTabular` environment. To use that option you need to load the `enumitem` package too.

So this slight adaptation of your code gives the desired output:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % <- needed by nicematrix to include tabular notes

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \NiceMatrixOptions{caption-above}
        \begin{NiceTabular}
            [caption = Big Five Persönlichkeitsmerkmale und Führung\tabularnote{aus dem Englischen übersetzt },
            tabularnote = \textit{Notiz:} Wir haben die Formel von Whitener's (1990) für den Standardfehler der mittleren Korrelation bei der Berechnung von Konfidenzintervallen verwendet ]
            {lccccccccc}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Durchschnitt} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{80\% GI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% KI} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
            Merkmal & k & N & r & $\rho$\tabularnote{$\rho$ = geschätzte korrigierte Schätzung} & SD & UG & OG & UG & OG \\
            \cmidrule{1-10}
            Neurotizismus & 48 & 8,025 & --.17 & --.24 & .18 & --.47 & --.01 & --.30 & --.18 \\
            Extraversion & 60 & 11,705 & .22 & .31 & .17 & .09 & .53 & .26 & .36 \\
            Offenheit & 37 & 7,221 & .16 & .24 & .11 & .09 & .38 & .19 & .28 \\
            Verträglichkeit & 42 & 9,801 & .06 & .08 & .17 & --.14 & .29 & .02 & .13 \\
            Gewissenhaftigkeit & 35 & 7,510 & .20 & .28 & .17 & .06 &.51 & .22 & .34 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: nicematrix with notes]

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot! There also is a way to achieve the annotation with the tablenotes environment provided by the threeparttable as mentioned by @leandriis, so now I have two solutions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `tabularray` does the same thing. You could also use the `ctan` package, but in my experience that doesn't do well with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Corrected is writing of decimal numbers formation (removed zeros from decimal numbers)

By use of the `tabularray` packages with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx˛` code is simple, MWE need only pone compilation for final result, numbers are aligned at decimal points:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}   % for formatting page layout
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         parse-numbers=false}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Big Five Persönlichkeitsmerkmale und Führung\TblrNote{a}},
remark{Notiz} = {Wir haben die Formel von Whitener's (1990) für den 
                Standardfehler der mittleren Korrelation bei der Berechnung von Konfidenzintervallen verwendet},
     note{a} = {aus dem Englischen übersetzt},
     note{b} = {$\rho$ = geschätzte korrigierte Schätzung}
                ]{colspec = {l c  Q[c, si={table-format= 2.3}]
                             *{7}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]}
                            },
                  row{1,2} = {guard}
                 }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Durchschnitt
        &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \qty{80}{\%} GI
                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \qty{80}{\%} KI
                                    &                       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-6}
    \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}
    \cmidrule[lr]{9-10}
Merkmal         & k & N & r & $\rho$ & SD & UG & OG & UG & OG \\
    \midrule
Neurotizismus       & 48 &  8,025 & -.17 & -.24 & .18 & -.47 & -.01 & -.30 & -.18 \\
Extraversion        & 60 & 11,705 &  .22 &  .31 & .17 &  .09 &  .53 &  .26 &  .36 \\
Offenheit           & 37 &  7,221 &  .16 &  .24 & .11 &  .09 &  .38 &  .19 &  .28 \\
Verträglichkeit     & 42 &  9,801 &  .06 &  .08 & .17 & -.14 &  .29 &  .02 &  .13 \\
Gewissenhaftigkeit  & 35 &  7,510 &  .20 &  .28 & .17 &  .06 &  .51 &  .22 &  .34 \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In the case, when is important that remark (Notes:) is before notes (1, b), than you need to define new `theme` for `talltblr`:

```
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytheme}%
{
\UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
\UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
}
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}%
{
\SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytheme}
}
```

which should be inserted before table or in preamble (for global settings) and change `talltblr` preamble to:

```
\begin{talltblr}[theme=mytheme,
caption = {Big Five Persönlichkeitsmerkmale und Führung\TblrNote{a}},
remark{Notiz} = {Wir haben die Formel von Whitener's (1990) für den
                Standardfehler der mittleren Korrelation bei der Berechnung von Konfidenzintervallen verwendet},
     note{a} = {aus dem Englischen übersetzt},
     note{b} = {$\rho$ = geschätzte korrigierte Schätzung}
                ]{colspec = {l c  Q[c, si={table-format= 5.0}]
                             *{7}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.2}]}
                            },
                  row{1,2} = {guard}
                 }
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. Appreciate your effort!

Comment: Should `\SetCell[c=3]{c}` maybe be `\SetCell[c=5]{c}`?

Comment: @Mico, good morning! You are right. I will correct ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that encases the tabular material and the legend in a `threeparttable` enviroment. That's all it takes to assure that the width of the legend is the same as that of the tabular material.

I would also make an effort to align the numbers in the 9 data columns on their (implicit or explicit) decimal markers. In the table shown below, this is achieved by employing the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% new:
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' env.
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out width of intercolumn spaces

\begin{threeparttable}
% (proviede a suitable \caption statement)

\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth}% % <-- set desired target width
       {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
       l 
       S[table-format= 2.0] 
       S[table-format= 5.0] 
  *{2}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
       S[table-format= 1.2]
  *{4}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
       }

\toprule
Merkmal 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Durchschnitt} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{80\% GI} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% KI} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{9-10}
& {$k$} & {$N$} & {$r$} & {$\rho$} & {SD$_{\rho}$} & {UG} & {OG} & {UG} & {OG} \\
\midrule
Neurotizismus      & 48 &  8025 & -.17 & -.24 & .18 & -.47 & -.01 & -.30 & -.18 \\
Extraversion       & 60 & 11705 &  .22 &  .31 & .17 &  .09 &  .53 &  .26 &  .36 \\
Offenheit          & 37 &  7221 &  .16 &  .24 & .11 &  .09 &  .38 &  .19 &  .28 \\
Verträglichkeit    & 42 &  9801 &  .06 &  .08 & .17 & -.14 &  .29 &  .02 &  .13 \\
Gewissenhaftigkeit & 35 &  7510 &  .20 &  .28 & .17 &  .06 &  .51 &  .22 &  .34 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\footnotesize
\lipsum[2][1-5] % <-- replace with text of legend.

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that example, really appreciate your effort!